# Wamp + VirtualHosts + virtual host specific settings/php.ini

Tags: php, wamp

So i would like to know if anyone have any idea how to set php settings to a specific virtualhost setup through wamp (windows obviously).

Here is a Guide to setting up a virtualhost in Wamp: http://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp

Assume i followed the guide. And assume my VHost is similar to:

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/awesome"
ServerName awesome</VirtualHost>
```

So i need to turn on specific php settings for this VHOST, say error reporting or php max file size for uploads etc, without actually affecting other VHosts on the same wamp setup.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: WAMP is not different from LAMP in this respect - you can use `.htaccess`: http://serverfault.com/questions/34078/how-do-i-set-up-per-site-php-ini-files-on-a-lamp-server-using-namevirtualhosts

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I use this methond when I'm developing to a special environment or where php settings must be overrided and I wont do it always from the running code.

Here's a basic config that will help you:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "path\to\root\folder"
ServerName your-hostname.com

# Here comes the boom
php_value memory_limit 128M # Means memory limit is raised to 128Mb
php_value post_max_size 500M # Means maximum size of post data is 500Mb
php_value upload_max_filesize 128M # Means maximum size of each uploaded file is 128Mb

</VirtualHost>
```

**Gist**

In virtualhost config, you can revalue ini variables by using this syntax

*php_value* *ini_variable_name* *value*

**Have fun!**